# Concatenate values based in 2 cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to obtain a summary of the units of each class per group, but I don't know how to do it. I tried different options but this is breaking my mind and I prefer not to use a macro, just a formula.

This is an example of what I want:

```
    Class | Group | Units | Summary
    ------|-------|-------|---------
    A     | G1    | 1     | 
    A     | G1    | 2     | 
    A     | G1    | 3     | 
    B     | G1    | 4     | A:"1,2,3";B:"4"
    B     | G2    | 5     | 
    C     | G2    | 6     | 
    C     | G2    | 7     | B:"5";C:"6,7"
    C     | G3    | 8     | 
    A     | G3    | 9     | C:"8";A:"9"
    A     | G4    | 0     | A:"0"
```

If you know how to help I would appreciate that.

Comment: Just use **Pivot table**

Comment: that seems like it will be a big complicated array formula because of the string concatenation (unless you have Excel 2016 with the [`TEXTJOIN` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)). If you show what you you have tried, or any attempts at solving the problem, you are a bit more likely to get better answers. Seems like it will be easier to solve with Excel VBA Macro.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @bzimor said - use pivot table. The source is your original table (class, group and units). Then when the pivot table placeholder appears, you put Group, Class and Units in the Column fields. The result looks like this:

[image: solution]

Of course, you can format the pivot table to look like you want it.

Comment: Yes that looks good for visual use, but the problem is that the file is for an external application which needs it all in a single cell to process the files. Anyway there are too many records to do it in columns. Thx anyway.